# export list value to pdf, xml, excel, text

Tags: java, spring, export

I need to generate xml, excel, pdf, text file from list what i retrieved from Database. I have used itext-1.3.jar for that and I have generated successfully. Here what i want to know means, is there is any other API is available like itext, if yes means kindly suggest me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want something else?

Comment: Actually I used itext displaytag api for previous task, now I want to learn something new about exporting list value to various file format.

Comment: If you want to learn about file format conversion, then how about making your own program? I've made plenty before.

Comment: Hey this is not about file format conversion, exporting list value into various file format. Actually I have used itext and displaytag for this, but in that, it only shows xml and pdf in browser, it didnt save the file. that's the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Apache [Java API To Access Microsoft Excel Format Files](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) can read/write Microsoft Excel 2003/2010 formats.